# What does the command 'chmod +x $1' in terminal do?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to install an application but I don't know what this command does:

```
chmod +x $1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `chmod` is used to

> change file mode bits
>
> ```
>    The format of a symbolic mode is  [ugoa...][[-+=][perms...]...],  where
>    perms  is  either zero or more letters from the set rwxXst, or a single
>    letter from the set ugo.  Multiple symbolic modes can be  given,  sepa‐
>    rated by commas.
> ```

(from the `man` or reference manual page for `chmod`).

The +x tells tells chmod to set the `execute` (or search for directories) flag on.

The $1 is usually used in scripts to mean the first parameter passed to the script. ($0 refers to the script itself) however if a `shift` has been executed, the parameters may have changed, so it's the first at the time of execution.